# How can we change background color of Progress dialog

Tags: android

How can we change background color of Progress dialog ?

```
progessDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please Wait....",true);
progessDialog.getWindow().setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);
```

Comment: progessDialog .getWindow().setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog); is not working properly can any help what I should use instead of this.

Comment: refer this http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-custom-indeterminate-progressbar-in-android-or-how-to-change-progressbar-style-or-color

Answer (score 1):

Change the color background

```
   final ProgressDialog pDialog = new  ProgressDialog(this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);

//final ProgressDialog pDialog = new  ProgressDialog(this);

// pDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new      ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));

    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

    pDialog.show();
```